# ASP.Net 6.0 + Identity не сохраняет авторизацию

Tags: авторизация, iis, asp.net-identity-3, iis-10, .net-6

Уважаемые участники, прошу Вас помочь вот с какой **проблемой**: есть сайт на **ASP.Net 6** с подключённой авторизацией **Microsoft Identity**, находящийся на хостинге под управлением **IIS 10 (WinServer 2022)**. **В разработке** авторизация пользователей (при постановке галки "*Запомнить меня*") живёт долго и счастливо. Однако **на сервере** где-то через **10-20 минут** авторизация теряется и приходится входить заново.

**Вот настройки IdentityOptions**

```
/* Настройки UserIdentityContext */
services.AddDbContext<UserIdentityContext>(
     options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:users_db"]));

IdentityBuilder ibuilder = services.AddIdentity<RnrmmUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>();
ibuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserIdentityContext>();
ibuilder.AddErrorDescriber<IdentityRussianErrorDescriber>();
ibuilder.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(static options => 
     options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

services.AddAuthentication().
Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(static options => {
     options.SlidingExpiration = true;
     options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
});

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(static options => {
     options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
     options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
     options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
     options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
     options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
     options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
     options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
     options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
     options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
});
```

**Вот мой Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Перенаправление на https" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\rnrmm_ru.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="w:\logs\rnrmm\errorlog" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**Как пробовал решить проблему:**
Пробовал увеличить жизнь куки следующим образом:

```
//Для поддержки сессий
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(static options =>
{
     options.Cookie.Name = ".rnrmm.session.data";
     options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
     options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
     //Время ожидания
     options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
});
```

Comment: А у вас пул в IIS не останавливается через 10 минут простоя случайно?

Comment: Да. Скорее всего.

Comment: Кстати, у меня в логах были ошибки ключа (не помню сейчас точно, что-то наподобие таких: 
    No XML encryptor configured. Key may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
    Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
    Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

Comment: Я, пытаясь решить эту проблему, выполнил эту инструкцию: https://cypressnorth.com/web-programming-and-development/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/ 30 минут -- авторизация держится...

Comment: Эта ошибка из логов говорит что надо ключ шифрования настраивать на сервере. Тогда будет пофигу как часто пул перезапускается.

Comment: Вы можете рассказать по-подробнее, что делать, пожалуйста. Хотя бы откуда начать...

Comment: ключевые слова Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, дальше сам не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема оказалась в IIS. Подробнее о баге в IIS [можно прочитать здесь](https://cypressnorth.com/web-programming-and-development/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/).

**РЕШЕНИЕ**
В пуле приложений выбрать пул сайта, открыть дополнительные параметры и в параметре "Загрузить профиль пользователя" (Load user profile) поставить значение true.

Comment: Уточнение: это не баг вообще-то